# Does boundedness imply total boundedness?

Tags: general-topology

> A metric space $(X, d)$ is said to be *totally bounded* if for every $\epsilon > 0,$ there is a finite covering of $X$ by $\epsilon$-balls.

Total boundedness implies boundedness.

My question is:  **does boundedness imply total boundedness?**

I'm not  able  to  find  a counter example; any hints or a solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how familiar you are with this, but as a hint: dig a little into the weird properties of $\ell^\infty$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For instance, the space $X=\Bbb N$ endowed with the 0-1 distance is bounded (and complete) but not totally bounded.

Answer (score 2):

The discrete metric on any infinite set is a counterexample.